# Turn on hardware acceleration if available (such Android 3+) with Android APK 2.2

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, android-compatibility, android-hardware

I developed a application for Android 3.0, and it's runs perfectly well, but the client insist on compatibility with 2.2 devices.

Disabling hardware acceleration, using Android Compatibility Package, a NIO-backport support (For tasks and executors) and some reimplementation of View methods I was able to port my app for Android 2.2 and works really good, but if I run this apk into a newer device the performance is extremely slowly, so I want to know how to turn on hardware acceleration if available but still uses my 2.2 APK.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest, either for the `<activity>` or the `<application>`.

This attribute will be ignored on older versions of Android, but will be honored on Android 3.0+.

This will require you to have set your build target to API Level 11 or higher, but you probably already have that.

Comment: The build target is 8 so it can run on Android 2.2 devices. Just adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  with minSdk=8 give errors.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos: The build target has nothing whatsoever to do with what devices it can run on.

Comment: True, it's really doesn't matter which build target it's points, since minSdkVersion is respected.

Comment: so if you put the API level to 11 or higher with minSdk=8 and you publish your app, it's gonna be available for android 2.2 users?

Comment: Although not important as the question, i wonder how would you suppress the warnings for XML?

Comment: @EnesBattal: Sorry, but I do not know what warnings you are referring to. You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you show your XML and show your warnings.

Answer (score 3):

If you need support devises with old OS (2.3.X and older) version, not add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest, try add this code in your java:

```
try { if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) getWindow().setFlags( 16777216, 16777216); } catch( Exception e) {} // FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED == 16777216 (0x01000000)
```

This is work in OS 3.0++ and not call error on 2.3.X and older.

Answer (score 2):

You can look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) to see how you can enable features based on Android version. You can do it with reflection too, but it is clunky.

Comment: Well, this helped me to run specific code per version. Thanks!